# SQLServer query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016. The following query is very slow (takes approx 40 sec):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CR_Data1]) AS main
UNPIVOT
([Dates] FOR [Tags] IN ([Submitted_on], [Analyzed_on], [Approved_on], 
[Postponed_on], [Assigned_on], [Opened_on], [Verified_on], [Rejected_on], 
[Resolved_on],  [Closed_on], [Cancelled_on], [Deferred_on], [Duplicate_on])
) AS b inner join CR_Data1 a on b.id=a.id
```

How can I optimize the execution? (adding indexes or maybe re-writing it?)

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: First of all look into query execution plan. Or show it to someone who can read it, if you can't

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ You can use this site to paste your plan and we can read it.

Comment: 1. In outer query and inner query add column names instead of * . 2. Instead of joining with Date column go for ID column where data have to compare with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

Comment: No `WHERE` clause? You want to unpivot the complete table?

Comment: I added the execution plan

Comment: @M.R. - Why do you need that `INNER JOIN` ? Is that `ID` column unique ? If yes, then you can remove that inner join

Comment: Link to execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJRYFiqXb

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing this as:

```
select m.*, v.*
from [dbo].[CR_Data1] m cross apply
     (values ('Submitted_on', [Submitted_on]), 
             ('Analyzed_on', [Analyzed_on]),
             ('Approved_on', [Approved_on]), 
             ('Postponed_on', [Postponed_on]), 
             ('Assigned_on', [Assigned_on]),
             ('Opened_on', [Opened_on]),
             ('Verified_on', [Verified_on]),
             ('Rejected_on', [Rejected_on]),
             ('Resolved_on', [Resolved_on]),
             ('Closed_on', [Closed_on]),
             ('Cancelled_on', [Cancelled_on]),
             ('Deferred_on', [Deferred_on]),
             ('Duplicate_on', [Duplicate_on])
     ) v(tag, date);
```

You don't seem to need any join, if I'm reading the query correctly.

Comment: I get "Incorrect syntax near ')'" Not sure what is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `CROSS APPLY` instead of `join`

Comment: Yes, it is CROSS APPLY. However the performance went down. Now it takes 49 sec instead of 40 sec